# In which Star Wars episodes is the history of Tatooine explained better

Tags: star-wars, tatooine

I was checking Wookieepedia article on Tatooine and came across this phrase

> After a terrible plague weakened the Rakata, the Kumumgah eventually
>   rebelled and managed to drive the Rakata off the planet. In response
>   they subjected the planet to an orbital bombardment that "glassed"
>   (that is, fused the silica in the soil into glass, which then broke up
>   over time into sand) the planet and boiled its oceans away

I am aware of some bombing which took place in Tatooine history, but never knew when it happened.

Which are the episodes which mention Tatooine's history and more specifically the bombing which changed the habitat of this planet of Annakin Skywalker and Luke Skywalker?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Kumumgah](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kumumgah) and [Kumumgah Rebellion](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kumumgah_Rebellion) Wikias list the sources (none of which are from G-canon or T-canon, so "episodes" don't figure into it - the info is all from Expanded Universe - games, books and comics):

- Star Wars: Knights of the Old Republic game (first mention)

Also,

- Galactic Phrase Book and Travel Guide
- The New Essential Guide to Alien Species
- Star Wars: The Official Starships & Vehicles Collection 26

The whole Rakatan Infinite Empire storyline was started in KOTOR game, and then expanded in multiple EU books/comics ( https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rakata#Appearances )

Answer (score 3):

None of the six movies really cover any of Tatooine's history - Wookieepedia is citing the *Star Wars: Knights of the Old Republic* game as its sources.

This is because of the multi-level canon that has been developed around Star Wars - things in the expanded universe (like games and books) are also canon, except where a movie explicitly contradicts them. Since the movies don't include Tatooine's history, the above paragraph is canon from the expanded universe.

Comment: Things in the EU are no longer considered to be canon